# cohomology monomorphism between grassmannians and product of projective spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology-cohomology

Let $S^1\times\cdots \times S^1( n\text{  times })=\prod_n U(1)\to U(n)$ be the inclusion. This induces a map between classifying spaces

$$
\prod_nBS^1\to BU(n).$$ i.e., 
$$
(\mathbb{C}P^\infty)^{\times n}\to BU(n).$$

The induced map in cohomology 
$$
f:H^*(BU(n))=\mathbb{Z}[y_1\cdots,y_n]\to H^*((\mathbb{C}P^\infty)^{\times n})=\otimes_n H^*(\mathbb{C}P^\infty)=\mathbb{Z}[x_1]\otimes \mathbb{Z}[x_2]\otimes\cdots\otimes \mathbb{Z}[x_n],
$$
$|x_i|=2$, $|y_i|=2i$ for all $i$.

Is $f$ a monomorphism? Why?

Comment: You have to check that all the functors preserve finite limits. I think it's true, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1):

Yes; in fact $f$ is an isomorphism onto $H^{\bullet}(BU(1)^n)^{S_n}$. This is an aspect of the splitting principle for complex vector bundles.

Comment: I still do not understand...

Comment: @RSQ: I'd like to be able to help you, but just saying "I don't understand" doesn't give me any feedback about how I can improve my explanation. What don't you understand?